Flutter app data does not work when app deployed on browser or android
I am getting the following error when debugging my flutter app on a web browser or on an android device. Debugging it on windows works just fine:
Error: NoSuchMethodError: 'split'
Dynamic call of null.
Receiver: Instance of 'LinkedMap<dynamic, dynamic>'
Arguments: [","]
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 297:3        throw_
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 1113:3   defaultNoSuchMethod
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/core_patch.dart 64:17                  noSuchMethod
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 1088:31  noSuchMethod
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 409:12   callNSM
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 420:25   _checkAndCall
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 620:10   callMethod
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 624:5    dsend
packages/myapp/main.dart 60:16                                               getStationForSearch
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 45:50                 <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1661:54                                               runUnary
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 162:18                                         handleValue
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 838:44                                         handleValueCallback
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 867:13                                         _propagateToListeners
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 643:5                                          [_completeWithValue]
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 713:7                                          callback
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 40:11                                   _microtaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 49:5                                    _startMicrotaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 181:7                 <fn>

The app deploys on the browser but it seems to break when I click on a search I implemented that needs to access a json file. How can I make the browser (and the android phone) see the location I have the json file with my data?
My data is in a local windows folder D:\dev\flutter-app\myapp\data\data.json
Thank you for your time!

It seems it not finding the split method and the expected Map (that could be the json file you're referring to) is of course returning null, have you tried putting the json file in  the assets folder and load it that way? Remember dart:html and dart:io are different for every environment to handle files.
PS: I would also double check the "main.dart" fiel at line 60 and column 16 , where the debugger stopped

60:16 in main.dart is where the code breaks. I do there a split ( var n = (m.split(',')); ) but since nothing is fetched I am doing a split in an empty string and that is why it breaks. However, I am trying to understand why when I debug on the android phone this only happens, and not on windows where it works fine. So on windows I am able to read the file but not on the android phone. Is there something I am missing when I debug on android that would help me read my data from the phone? I inspect also build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk and data is there! Why can't I read it?

After many hours of debugging here is what is happening.
When I debug on my Android phone, there is an active work profile that prohibits the debugger to access the data/data folder (to access the Device Explorer in your phone, Pair your phone with WiFi or use a USB cable, and on Android Studio go to View > Tool Windows > Device Explorer).
The error in the Device Explorer reads:
Error executing shell command pm list packages
It seems that still there is no workaround for this unless you remove your work profile and uninstall any secure folders you may have.
I need to try debug the app in an Android phone with no work profile and no secure folders installed. Bummer!
